# Fully custom application installer

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

At the moment I have written my own installer that copies files from resources or downloads them online

I know about things like wix, etc., but I have specific requirements:

1. Have only one window, the user selects (if he wants) the installation folder and a list of pre-installed plugins that the installer downloads from the application's plugin store.
2. This window has an interactive animation that uses a lightweight render engine

And as I said, it's completely ready, the application uses C# and does everything as it should, except that the installer requires administrator rights and falls under the radar of antiviruses

That's my question, how do I solve these problems? Do I need to request elevation to administrator, as well as somehow add the installer to the whitelist? Perhaps it needs to be signed somehow?

Comment: All installers require administrator privileges, and unsigned installers will always trigger AV software. You can't whitelist an unsigned installer.

Comment: If your installer doesn't do anything that requires admin privileges, you don't need admin privileges. But, if your program has _setup_ or _install_ in its name, the OS guesses it needs admin rights. You can get around the automatic behavior by using a _manifest_ to refuse admin privileges. But, if you do that and do need the additional rights, your installer will fail